# UIScroll View Delegate not calling ScrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation

Tags: iphone, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have implemented the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol in my .h file and i have implemented the

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

method in my .m class. when the scrolling is done in my table view other delegate method of scrollview are getting called, but when scrolling ends, `-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` is not getting called. I am bit stuck in this.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` is called when a programmatic-generated scroll finishes.
`-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` is called when a user-swipe scroll finishes.

Comment: +1 and thank you for explaining the difference between the two delegate methods. I think this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: And if you also want to react on when a user drags the scroll view, but releases it without the scroll view scrolling further, you should also implement the ``scrollViewDidEndDragging`` method, you can check the bool parameter ``willDecelerate`` to decide on whether you have to execute the code here or in the ``scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`` method.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem ... Try using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Have used the following in my delegate class:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSLog(@"lol");
}
```

works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks big help. Have you filed a bug report about this? I've just submitted rdar://8810881 http://openradar.appspot.com/8810881.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the issue was i did not include the delegate code:

```
self.myScrollView.delegate=self;
```

Hope this helps someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**?

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}
```