# How do I know when UIScrollView stops decelerating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, events, uiscrollview

I would like to add an animation when `UIScrollView` stops?
How should I implement this? By using a timer and checking the decelerating value?
Or I thought in 4.0 blocks are recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the UIScrollViewDelegate's [scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) method. There's also [scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:) to inform you that the scrollview is now slowing down.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I also found this link useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969256/uiscroll-view-delegate-not-calling-scrollviewdidendscrollinganimation/4909621#4909621

Answer (score 1):

Two things to remember here. First of all, set the delegate for the UIScrollView. Then implement your desired behavior in one or both of these delegate methods

```
-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

The difference between those two is explained in [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969256/uiscroll-view-delegate-not-calling-scrollviewdidendscrollinganimation/4909621#4909621).

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll view delegate method

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: