# scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation doesn't get called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a simple UIScrollView and a UIPager, whenever I scroll through the scrollview I want to change my pager, but for some reason `(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` isn't being called.

My delegate is working since `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` just works, am I forgetting something here?

Or is there another way you can change a `UIPager` when the scrollview is being scrolled through?

Answer (score 6):

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html
>
> The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of
> the UIScrollView and setContentOffset:animated: and
> scrollRectToVisible:animated: methods, but only if animations are
> requested.

The following two methods call will only work. must be animated value is `YES`.

```
[myScrollView setContentOffset:<#(CGPoint)#> animated:YES];
[myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:<#(CGRect)#> animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had mistaken `(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and `(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

[UIScroll View Delegate not calling ScrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969256/uiscroll-view-delegate-not-calling-scrollviewdidendscrollinganimation)